# Creating SharePoint 2007 list items via the Web Dav interface

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint 2007 (both Moss and Wss) exposes document libraries via web dav, allowing you to create documents via essentially file system level activities (e.g. saving documents to a location).

SharePoint also seems to expose lists via the same web dav interface, as directories but they are usually empty.  Is it possible to create or manipulate a list item somehow via this exposure?

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

Longer answer: Kinda. Any item stored in sharepoint is in a list, including files. But not all lists have files. A document library is a list with each element being a file+metadata. Other lists (like announcments) are just metadata. Only lists that contain files are exposed via webdav, and even then you are limited to mucking around with the file - there is no way to use webdav (afaik) to edit the metadata.

Hope this helps.

Oisin.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. The only thing exposed to webdav is a list item's attachment (or a library's documents). Even if you bring up a file's properties in explorer, there's no options for list data.

If you're working with Office 2007 documents, you can create a [document information panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550037.aspx) that can be tied into sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

No, but in my experience most things looking to speak WebDAV to something are pretty much expecting to work with files or documents of some sort.  Since non-library lists in SharePoint don't really have an associated file (yeah, they can have attachments, but that's not the same), then effectively the primary construct WebDAV is built around (document) is missing.  What would you be Authoring and Versioning?

If you are writing your own client, there are [robust web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx) for interacting with lists (both the library and non-library varieties)